# Is there a way to turn off use site covariance in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Note: As of Kotlin beta 4, this problem is fixed.

---

```
fun test(a: List<String>) { }
```

The above Kotlin code generates byte code:

```
public static final void test(@NotNull List<? extends String> a)
{
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(a, "a");
}
```

I have submitted an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10412), but I need to circumvent this bug temporarily. Is there a way to mark `a` as invariant?

Comment: What particular problem does that causes you on the use site?

Comment: This is a badly written question, and should be updated to say what was expected vs. actually happened.  The lack of this caused confusion in answers and comments.  Can you edit your question for clarity?

Comment: I don't think I need to. This question has been answered well. What was expected was stated in the question (title), "turn off use site covariance". Denis Zharkov obviously had no problem understanding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in out dev-branch and will be available within next public release.
Also there will be `JvmSuppressWildcards`/`JvmWildcard` annotations allowing to control generic signature.

As a temporary workaround you can use `MutableList<String>` in Kotlin declaration

Comment: why is it a bug? Should not it be that way?

Comment: @voddan I have explained the problem in the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10412).

Comment: @DenisZharkov Thank you. "Next public release", do you mean beta 4?

Comment: @wintetYoung what you said is not a problem. In what (bad) the way does that affect your code /project?

Comment: @voddan It a compatibility issue. Kotlin declares 100% java compatibility. I have elaborated the situation in that detail in the issue, and you don't see it as a problem? The description I filed in the issue is what I am encountering in my project. I cannot share my project code, it's proprietary. But I really think I have done my best to explain it.

Comment: ok, so it is a **binary** compatibility issue, not a bug. Mind you that In the sources all should be good. As @denis said, an annotation is it what is gonna solve this

Comment: @voddan I don't think it's a binary compatibility issue. The java source referencing the method does not compile. Why it's so hard to admit it's a bug, I don't understand... Anyway, it's been fixed.

Comment: @WinterYoung Yes, I mean Beta 4

Comment: @DenisZharkov Beta 4 is out. I'm wondering why `Map<K, V>` generates bytecode of `Map<K, ? extend V>`. This still breaks compatibility, doesn't it?

Comment: @WinterYoung Yes, there will be wildcard if V can effectively have subtypes, but now you can use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation. 
You can find some explanation about variance generics in the [document](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/blob/4d6ca1b9193700c653b09cb0cc42dc5b0db8f971/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.md)